# My website always redirect to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: redirect

My new website always redirect to http://zendtest.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. How to change this to http://zendtest.com/index.php ?

Can anyone help me ?